# Get child class from jsp:useBean

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I am working on a legacy system which has some old jsp files.
`testParent` class has set of `testChild` class. `testParent` has a method which returns a single `testChild` object and `testChild` object has `numberIWant`.
Method in `testParent`

```
public TestChild giveTestChild()
    {
        TestChild testChild= this.testChilderen.iterator().next();

        return testChild;

    }
```

and `testChild.getNumberIWant`

this how I tried to implement in jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="parentClass" class="package.TestParent" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="childClass" class="package.TestChild" scope="request"/>

<input:text name="numberIWant" bean="parentClass.giveTestChild()"
                          attributesText="id='numberIwant' " size="20"/>
```

But its not working. Because of the Hibernate I `testParent` is always available to me and dont want to make separate call for `testChild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes should be  valid java beans, so they have getters and setters to be able to use with `jsp:useBean` tag. To get the value of the testChild bean you can use

```
<input type="text" name="numberIWant" value="<jsp:getProperty name="childClass" property="numberIWant"/>"  size="20"/>
```

To get the value of the testChild bean using parentClass use

```
<% testChild = parentClass.getTestChild(); %>
<input type="text" name="numberIWant" value="<jsp:getProperty name="childClass" property="numberIWant"/>"  size="20"/>
```